# From ms access table how to paste required data form array (getrows) to excel specific ranges using vba

Tags: excel, vba

My below code shows no error, when run, but I don't know how to extract required/particular field values into my excel sheet.

```
Sub getdatafromaccesstoanarray()

    Dim cn      As Object   'Connection
    Dim rs      As Object   'Recordset
    Dim vAry()  As Variant  'Variant Array
    Dim dbPath  As String   'Database Path
    Dim dbName  As String   'Database Name
    Dim txt     As String

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    dbPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    dbName = "NewDB.accdb"

    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & dbPath & dbName & ";"

    rs.Open "SELECT * FROM BILLDETAILS WHERE BILLDETAILS.SN_AUTO =100;", cn

    vAry = rs.GetRows()

    'now when the data is copied to my array how can i paste specific values from this data to
    'cells in my excel sheet
    'like
    'on active sheet
    '[a1] = vAry(value1)
    '[a2] = vAry(value3)
    '[a3] = vAry(value8)

    'and other values like wise


    rs.Close
    cn.Close

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

If there any other way to do this then please let me know. 
Thanks!

Comment: You would need to find the UBound of the array and the last row of data on your Excel Sheet then use a for loop to write to the next empty row of excel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to copy the recordset into the sheet you can use the CopyFromRecordset method to dump the table into the sheet by specifying the top left corner:

```
 Range("a1").copyfromrecordset rs
```

If you want to put specific fields in specific positions you can loop

```
Do While not rs.eof
   range("a2")=rs(0)
   range("b2")=rs(1)
    'etc....
  rs.movenext
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, It worked Fine. I am so grateful to you.